# Visual Studio Build does not download all NuGet packages without a project reference

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, .net-5

I'm trying to understand why removing a project reference prevents my build from downloading all the NuGet packages it needs.  This is with Visual Studio 2019

- Application A (.NET 5) holds a project reference to Assembly B.
- Assembly B uses a NuGet package C.
- When the build starts, NuGet Package C get downloaded automatically.

This is all vanilla expected, .NET stuff.

But then I realized that A does not actually use any B-specific types.  B is a Prism Module that only loads dynamically if the user has a license for it and clicks a button.  So A doesn't even always load "B".

So I removed A's project reference to B.  I don't want some future developer to accidentally think they can start referring to types in B.  (We don't ship all modules all the time).  Technically now, there is no project in the solution that holds a reference to  B.  But it's still part of the build.  I did set up the build dependencies so that B would still build before A but there's no longer a project reference..

Then I did a clean build.  Visual Studio said it completed successfully.  And I see Assembly B got built.   But the build process did NOT retrieve NuGet package C (that B depends on).  Testing has revealed it will not retrieve C unless application A actually holds a project reference to B.

Is there some way around this?  If I'm building all assemblies, why would MSBuild not download all assemblies dependent NuGet packages.  Is there some setting I can change to make it happen.

Comment: Could you describe how you set Assembly B as build dependencies?

Comment: I used the "Project Dependencies" dialog.  Specifically, in Solution Explorer, I right click on the project for Application A and choose `Build Dependencies >> Project Dependencies` from the context menu.  That brings me to the "Project Dependencies" dialog.  There, I make sure that when "A" is selected in the "Projects" dropdown, "B" is checked in the list of other projects

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for the explanation. Is Assembly B based on .NET? I tested but I couldn't reproduce your issue on my side. You mentioned NuGet C get downloaded, so where was it downloaded to? `...\.nuget\packages` folder? Or where else? I am willing to test, if you could share a reproducible simple sample or some detailed steps/information.

Comment: Both projects are C# and based on .NET 5.  The assemblies are downloaded automatically by Visual Studio (MSBuild, I guess...?) during the build to the solution build output folder.  Each project directs its output to a common folder.  For example, for a release build they both have `Build >> Output` path set to `..\..\x64\Release`  For a debug build it is `..\..\x64\Debug`.  And since I'm building for Windows, the build automatically creates a subdirectory in each of those places called `net5.0-windows`.  All output binaries, including NuGet ones, end up there

Comment: I was able to reproduce it in a test app.  Created a WPF.NET 5 application..  Added a WPF .NET 5 class library assembly to it.  Made the assembly reference a NuGet package (I chose one called "Stateless" that's available at NuGet .org).  Made both send output to a common output folder as described above.  Also changed both to build only on x64 instead of "AnyCpu" (not sure that matters).  Made app have a build dependency on the assembly.  If I build, nothing gets downloaded.  If the app has a *project reference* to the assembly, stateless.dll appears in the output folder

Comment: I'm wondering if I should report this to Microsoft as a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else ever has this problem:

I asked this question of Microsoft.  They said that this behavior is by design: If a DLL-generating assembly ("B") uses a NuGet package, then the only way that package will be downloaded at build time is if an assembly that generates an EXE has a *project reference* to B.   Merely having a build dependency is not enough.

No explanation as to why.  I still think the behavior should be different for reasons I mentioned in the question and comments above.  They said it is a question for the .NET team and referred it to them.  I finally got a reply that said, I can make this behavior happen by adding an attribute (named `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies`)  to my Assembly B's project file.

So I did.  Added this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And it worked.  With this attribute set to true, an assembly that requires a NuGet package will get that assembly in the output folder regardless of whether or not anyone has a project reference to it.

(One could argue that this is a RTFM sort of question.  But learning MSBuild and its ins-and-outs is one of many things I "eventually need to do" on my plate)